# First name, last name and image not showing

Tags: django

I'm new to python and django. I have a custom django model and a profile model that is working perfectly. But i have a challenge.  When a user is logged in, he can view his profile completely, but when users try ro view other users profile, the first_name, last_name and the image of the user to be accessed is not showing.  How do i resolve this.

Comment: You resolve it by fixing the code. Which you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the permission classes if you have applied them.
2. Check the User ID/details being sent to the backend whether they are being sent and if they belong to the accessed user or not.
3. Use debugging tools - like pdb and console on the browser to see what is happening.